# Como fazer o autofocus com jquery

Tags: jquery

Eu queria saber como fazer `document.getElementById('input').focus()` com jquery. Segundo o que eu vi na documentação `$('input').focus()` foi depreciado e eu não consegui fazer funcionar com `$('input').on('focus')`. Queria saber o que estou fazendo errado ou se existe outra forma.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se essa é a forma certa, mas consegui fazer funcionar usando `$('input').trigger('focus')`

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).